# What is ShellBackButton, with ShellBackButtonUpdated event, for in Template 10?

Tags: uwp, template10

I thought using the ShellBackButton in the PageHeader (with Template 10 framework) is a cool thing but the Back navigation doesn't update the page. The page Frame changes, but the page shows blank.

Is it because ShellBackButton is not linked to the navigation system, and if so how do you get the ShellBackButton (and ShellBackButtonUpdated) to work?

**[UPDATE WITH MORE INFO BASED ON COMMENT]**

In view page XAML (wiring to the view-model page):

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:DetailPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

In view page code-behind: BackButton hits the overridden Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation events

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // BackButton hits this event as well as OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    // and OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
}
```

In viewmodel page (inherits Template10.Mvvm.ViewModelBase):

```
public class DetailPageViewModel : Template10.Mvvm.ViewModelBase
{
    // Navigation now takes place via overridden methods in 
    // Template10.Services.NavigationService.INavigable
}
```

This raises a more specific sub-question to my original with better clarity:

How can you make the ShellBackButton, which currently hits the **Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation** navigation events in view page, **INSTEAD** hit the **Template10.Services.NavigationService.INavigable** navigation events in view-model? If this can be done (which I don't know how), then, the problem is solved.

Comment: not designed to update your page merely a navigation tool, updating your page is up to you as the developer.

Comment: tnxs for replying. the button was working as expected before I change my pages to viewmodel. does that mean it works with view but not viewmodel?

Comment: how are you viewmodels wired up and what is their base inheritance? How are you telling the pages about the viewmodels?  Just update your existing question with the answers to these questions.

Comment: thank u @mvermef for helpful comment. added info as u say.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so get rid of that override in the code behind of the page it has no place being there.  Pretty much all `Pages` will be nearly blank in code-behind with exception of the constructor.

This doesn't mean view related things can't be placed here since in the `ShellPage` of the `HamburgerMenu` there is a lot done in the code-behind, but it's specialized for that.

Next place the override into the viewmodel, problem should be solved.  Since the Datacontext for the page is now the viewmodel you defined, you were confusing the service. Or at least it doesn't know that the override exists since the viewmodel isn't actually setup for it.

[Template10.MVVM.ViewModelBase](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Mvvm/ViewModelBase.cs) has `INavigable` inherited, therefore now you will have at least 2 overrides in total, 1 for `OnNavigateToAsync` and `OnNavigateFromAsync`,  keep in mind that in come versions the Async flavors will probably go away.

I assumed you installed the Template10 vsix from the gallery, that should have also installed templates for ViewModels as well as code snippets.

HTH,

Morgan.

Comment: thanks @mvermef. My view page code-behind is blank except for initialization. I showed Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation overrideables to illustrate the point. I follow u and my view page and viewmodel are as u say. problem is ShellBackButton tap DOES NOT hit viewmodel's navigation handlers although page changes and hits the contructor (ShellBackButton is driven by view page Frame object as PageHeader that contains ShellBackButton is bound to Frame). Everything is perfect in view page, but viewmodel navs don't seem to know ShellBackButton. Could it be oversight by template 10 developers?

Comment: what template are you using of T10?  Hamburger, Minimal, Blank?

Comment: I am using a version of Hamburger project. I think I found the problem a few moment ago. Intellisense suggested I change NavigationService.Frame to NavigationService.FrameFacade and I obeyed and that is how the problem started (I think). I will check everything and post what comes up. I think this is the problem as ShellBackButton started working in viewmodel just like view page.

Comment: Okay, I can confirm that the problem was due to changing NavigationService.Frame to NavigationService.FrameFacade which I did because intellisense suggested NavigationService.Frame as being obsolete. As it turned out, this wasn't a design issue but will serve others time if them run into the same problem.

Comment: I meant to say in above ... 'will SAVE others time...'. Pity that comments cannot be edited beyond a brief period of time. Sorry for the typo.